# One day visit to Istanbul Turkey during International travel

Tags: visas, transit-visas, us-citizens, turkey

I am a US citizen traveling from Kathmandu to US through Istanbul, Turkey. I have a 19 hour layover in Istanbul. Can I visit the area near the airport or stay in a near-by hotel while in transit? Are there visa requirements to leave and re-enter the airport during this 19 hour layover?

Comment: Get an eVisa which is cheap and quick and don’t miss touring Istanbul. It’s lovely!

Comment: And if by any chance you are flying Turkish Airways then you can avail their free Istanbul tours or even free hotel whichever option you like.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a transit visa, from the [Ministry Of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> **United States of America**: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey.

Because you are leaving the airport, you must have a visa. An E-Visa can be obtained [here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).